# Product with multi-dimensional matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, power-series, taylor-expansion

We know the power series in scalar case $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$
$$
f(x)=a_0x^0+a_1x^1+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\dots
$$
so what is the extension to the multi-dimensional case $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$
$$
f(x)=(A_0)_{1\times 1}+(A_1)_{1\times n}\cdot x+x^{\mathrm T}\cdot(A_2)_{n\times n}\cdot x+x^{\mathrm T}\cdot\mathop{(A_3)_{n\times n\times n}}_{\dot x}\cdot x+\dots?
$$

> So what is the right way?
>
> Can I define a product "$*$" (for example) to rewrite the multi-dimensional case similar as the scalar case
>   $$
> f(x)=(A_0)_{1\times 1}+(A_1)_{1\times n}*x+(A_2)_{n\times n}*x*x+(A_3)_{n\times n\times n}*x*x*x+\dots
> $$
>   How to do it, and can you help to give the exact definition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Power_series_in_several_variables).

Comment: @Bye_World Thanks for your reference!